# mongodb and php how to output results using geoNear

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to output results using the geoNear command using PHP but what I keep getting back is one document that I can retrieve using print_r.

This is my example the search 1 works fine but search 2 doesn't do anything.

```
    <?php
    $mongo = new Mongo();

    $collection = $mongo->selectDB('users')->selectCollection('user');

    $lng = -2.28;
    $lat = 53.46;
    $lnglat = array($lng, $lat);
    $query = array('loc' => array('$near' => $lnglat));

    //search 1
    $cursor = $collection->find($query)->limit(10);


    while($cursor->hasNext()){
        $user = $cursor->getNext();
        echo $user['username'] . "<br />";
    };

    //search 2
    $cursor2 = $mongo->selectDB('users')->command(array(
                    'geoNear' => 'user',
                    'near' => $lnglat,
                    'spherical' => true,
                    'num' => 10 )); 

    while($cursor2->hasNext()){
        $user = $cursor2->getNext();
        echo $user['username'] . "<br />";
    };
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command()` doesn't return a cursor, just an associative array.  Just do:

```
$result = $mongo->selectDB('users')->command(array(
                'geoNear' => 'user',
                'near' => $lnglat,
                'spherical' => true,
                'num' => 10 )); 

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks I released this and just used the $near search and used PHP to work out the distances between users.